# How to properly send raw html code to gmail using phpmailer in php

Tags: php

Am sending raw code to gmail via phpmailer. when  I tried to run the code, the code is formatted in the **gmail** instead of appearing as raw codes.

I want the code in the message body to appear the way it is in the email as per below

. In order words, how do i make the code to appear as raw codes in gmail

```
<html>
<script>
alert('This is your Code');
</script>
<body><p>
<b>Display as raw codes.</b>
</p>
</body></html>
```

**below is the code**

```
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;


$email_subject='my codes';
$recipient_email='reciever@gmail.com';
$recipient_name='Ann';
$sender_name='john';

$mycode = "<html>
<script>
alert('This is your Code');
</script>
<body><p>
<b>Display as raw codes.</b>
</p>
</body></html>";


// Load Composer's autoloader
require 'vendor/autoload.php';


$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    


    //Server settings goes here
    

    $mail->setFrom('nancy@gmail.com', "$sender_name");
      $mail->addAddress($recipient_email, $recipient_name);     // Add a recipient
  

    // Content
    $mail->isHTML(true); // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = $email_subject;
    $mail->Body =  $mycode;
    //$mail->AltBody = ""; // for Plain text for non-HTML mails

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message successfully sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
 echo "Message not sent. Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";

}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> $mail->isHTML(true); // Set email format to HTML
> ```

Don't do that.

If you want the message to be displayed as plain text, then don't tell the client that it should be displayed as HTML.

```
$mail->isHTML(false);
```